# Signal = SIGTRAP (Trace/breakpoint trap) - C

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, signals

I have a pointer to struct declared as :

```
typedef struct label{
   struct label * next;
   char arr[]
}label_t;
```

I have allocated the struct in this way :

```
int length;
char * str;
label_t * pointer;
scanf("%d\n", &length);
str = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
if(str){
   fgets(str, length + 2, stdin);
   pointer = malloc(sizeof(label_t) + length*sizeof(char));
   if(pointer){
      strcpy(pointer->arr, str);
      free(pointer);
   }
}
```

When i try to free the memory allocated this error comes out and I don't understand why. I think it's caused by the array declared in that way because if I use a pointer to char and free the pointer to struct it has no problems.

EDIT :

my error was doing this

```
str = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
if(str){
   fgets(str, length + 2, stdin);
   pointer = malloc(sizeof(label_t) + length*sizeof(char));
   if(pointer){
      strcpy(pointer->arr, str);
      free(pointer);
   }
}
```

instead of this

```
str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length+2));
if(str){
   fgets(str, length + 2, stdin);
   pointer = malloc(sizeof(label_t) + (length+2)*sizeof(char));
   if(pointer){
      strcpy(pointer->arr, str);
      free(pointer);
   }
}
```

I was not considering two final chars "\n\0" and i was going out of bounds.
Thanks to @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: All we can do is ***guess*** since there's just not enough information in the question. But my own guess is that you go out of bounds of the array. And it's a perfectly fine way to declare the array, by the way, and is supported as a [*flexible array member*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

Comment: And please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also don't forget how to create a [mre].

Comment: A few things with your new code: First of all, why do you allocate memory dynamically for `str`? Is `length` unknown at compile time? How do you get `length`? Then how is the variable `k` related to `length`? What is the value of `k`? What is the value of `length`? Then do you remember that strings are ***null-terminated***? So a string with `X` characters needs space for `X + 1` characters to fit the null-terminator? Lastly, `strcpy` have no bound checking. If the string in `str` is longer than `length - 1` (`-1` because of the terminator), then `strcpy` goes out of bounds of `pointer->arr`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i get length from a file , so i don't know the length of string before reading this file. Each string from input has length+2 chars ( string + \n\0)

Comment: Your edit makes it even worse: You allocate `lenght` characters, then you read up to `length + 2` characters into the memory. If `length` is the length of the line not including the newline and the null-terminator, then you need to allocate `length + 2` characters, for both `str` and the flexible array member.